# Is there more than one Solar System?

Tags: astronomy, terminology, solar-system

Please confirm:  there is only one [Solar System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_System).  Since 'Solar' is an adjective derived from the noun 'Sol' and as there is only one star named Sol, there is only one Solar System.  To call the system of planets and other heavenly bodies orbiting Regulus a 'Solar' system would be as incorrect as calling Charon a 'Martian' moon.

Comment: The word solar is not used exclusively in the way you assert, just as galaxy is no longer used for the Milky Way. Before Hubble, Slipher, and LeMaitre, there was only one galaxy. Go investigate the etymology of galaxy.  So, yes, there are more solar system.

Comment: This seems overly pedantic. Nobody calls our star 'Sol' in everyday usage. Few will confuse our solar system with another system of planets orbiting some other star. So, what is the point, and why would physicists be the final say? Perhaps English Language SE might be a better place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Technically another system should be called a 'stellar system'.

Comment: I am not sure I like "stellar system," as I have used that for a system of binary stars, for example.

Comment: @MarkFischler, binaries, trinaries, etc are systems, as are planetary systems.  I would say that a planetary, single stellar system is a subset of stellar systems.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense you are correct. It would be proper to refer to a collection of planets and comets and meteors orbitting around, say, Regulus as a "single-star-centric planetary system"

But one can excuse the shorter term "other solar systems" as being clear in meaning and easier to say.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be apparent for monolingual  English speakers that the word solar refers to the sun and not any generic star, it is certainly clear for any speaker of a Romance language that it is so. Hence the expression “solar systems” in the plural stands out as immediately bizarre when one means to refer to other planetary systems, or star systems (depending on whether you prefer to emphasize the stellar member of the system of the planetary ones).

It would be a favor to the international community to retire the use of “solar system” in this sense.